# How can I make a repeatable table cell within an XML Template?

Tags: xml, ms-word, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, bi-publisher

I'm trying to create a calendar with an xml template, and I've got a query retrieving some date related fields: year, month, month_day, week_day, week_year, appointments

From that I've been able to create a barebones calendar by grouping years, and months and displaying each row with the day info. Currently it looks something like this:

2023

DECEMBER

<table_cell>
01
Friday
11:00 - Dentist
</table_cell>

The problem here is that instead of repeating the day cells contiguously it creates a new table for each day.

Is there any way to make it repeat the cells next to each other?

Thanks!